# Getting "413 Request Entity Too Large" when exporting a Google Workspace document

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to export a Google Slides file using the Drive API. To do that, I'm using one of the export links mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files#resource-representations).

Generally, it works fine, however for some of the files I'm getting "413 Request Entity Too Large". From what I've seen so far:

1. When I use the export link mentioned above, I get a "307 Temporary Redirect" response. It has a "Location" header with the actual download link.
2. It's when using the second URL when I see the "413 Request Entity Too Large"

I believe it's actually about the URL length (even though I would have expected a 414 code?). The reasons I believe it's about the URL length are:

1. When using the API explorer and entering a huge fileId, I get the same response.
2. A similar limitation is mentioned for URL in a batch request ([source](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/batch)):

> Note: There is an 8000 character limit on the length of the URL for each inner request.

With that, my questions would be:

1. Is my assumption correct, i.e. that this issue is about URL length?
2. How to work around this issue?

**UPDATE**
More details about the URLs and how I execute requests.

The export link is something like: `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=1E3AU3Tf3zB_rest_of_id_goes_here&exportFormat=pptx&xoauth_requestor_id=myemail@example.com`

Then I use the following code to build and execute the download request:

```
Drive client = …;
HttpRequest httpRequest = client.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadUrl));
httpRequest.setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(
    new LoggingRequestHandler(
            new HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(backoff)
    )
);
httpRequest.setIOExceptionHandler(new HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler(backoff));
httpRequest.execute().getContent();
```

From what I can see in the logs, the only headers on this request are `accept-encoding` and `authorization`.

The response I get is:

```
307 Temporary Redirect

cache-control: [no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate]
content-encoding: [gzip]
content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8]
date: [Thu, 11 Feb 2021 08:23:51 GMT]
expires: [Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT]
location: [https://doc-0c-70-slides.googleusercontent.com/export/al07ue7kob156ds9t1lb1bv2es/r9ibb6n2phn0fv6ekpkl5q005s/1613031830000/108922609109226272057/108922609109226272057/1E3AU3Tf3zB_zp9fs82X5dqjwgn9OjmzFAec_nwxAt4o?id=1E3AU3Tf3zB_zp9fs82X5dqjwgn9OjmzFAec_nwxAt4o&exportFormat=pptx&xoauth_requestor_id=myemail@example.com&dat=ANCXxGiNgFZ2HtpZQgpXbua_7ayLwBdpLeMWK1kQj6EaoYJzqfs9mMlnrkZnuk_3MMj7IMiHZWw4JqhPVjB1EKjjJ8Mnv-DNFCmCr0FZf9UjySxI4LnQDDOvQKxEdnSNaPciQlrFYqsBXlYcWh0PpRVzXWlSHn9KSTe2Tt2wDUp4gT-jLu-GfNYY42b00tUvtbMJ5Wu23jKe_uZrAqy7rxUksdkpbI-UEsuE8D5jLpeEK_8ntJd6wjKWnc50enENMhqiBKCFTD7l3KguteBN4rNUhQZgvTcJOisKEBmJ_7gRLM4AChC6bg1rccvvcJfIe76-Jg0l4OdvSsTE9UnOlCbPWKSyrBpQTqrqRiRrkWhrFr5ZZ62Gw-IJsWkiiltSueEuTsoJZPyqX_SWZgIoCoEQshd7wM-K7_CJYNj27F2pUQf1IB9Rs_KM3GaI3MPP31q3hDrHWr-OLidHihez8HcRkUyn-HlLX7i3EaMRVRqEEfPYLXfypR342WFZveFqpV1OTeG-ctznI6mRSMcCL1BskV_K8Wt4xo08YxwvUXx3YBcYBw7jIbsXn6m_WEFYTIbYJC_Bx-NfIlQfdxGiB2gS6Afnkuz41kU6xpEQY4_LqWRi30fQxxLORyEFsnC3i5yOoDL8PYwv4Q0LX5mBfVpe4BV1EvYjAFWLaZfgNEva8_Q8wNHhBaP6fSsdEqKnYPrI9sRiNGFY23nOTPFcxvNPHHamSBTHHrylYCBI8MSrrQzhTDRZ-LXVlk7NV3lzxTR7RDDGNA]
transfer-encoding: [chunked]
alt-svc: [h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"]
server: [GSE]
x-content-type-options: [nosniff]
pragma: [no-cache]
p3p: [CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."]
x-frame-options: [SAMEORIGIN]
content-security-policy: [base-uri 'self';object-src 'self' blob:;report-uri https://docs.google.com/presentation/cspreport;script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-5eTqTCwMOyiL5bwXBOSMzQ' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'unsafe-eval']
set-cookie: [NID=209=blahblah; expires=Fri, 13-Aug-2021 08:23:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly]
x-xss-protection: [1; mode=block]
```

After that, the Google Drive SDK (well, it's underlying `HttpTransport` class) follows this redirect, using the value from the `location` header as the request URL. The response I get then is `413 Request Entity Too Large`.

Comment: About `however for some of the files I'm getting "413 Request Entity Too Large".`, can I ask you about the differences between this file and other worked files?

Comment: At the moment, I'm still not aware of any differences. I don't own the files which didn't work, so I have limited access to those.

Comment: `When I use the export link` Could you provide more details about this? How are you trying to access this URL? Can you provide more information about the request? (headers, body, etc.). Also, can you clarify the formatting of this URL? Is there a code you're working on?

Comment: @Iamblichus I've updated the question with more details about the requests and responses, and some code I use.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. When trying to access an export link like the one you mentioned, I get a 200. This happens when I access it via browser as well as through script. Does this happen for all presentations, or just for a specific one?

Comment: That happens only for a number of specific presentations. Btw, you get the same error if you go to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get, and then enter a huge file ID in the API explorer (e.g. an ID with 15 000 chars).

Comment: Can you provide a sample presentation (free of sensitive information) that can be used to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: @Iamblichus I'll need to check that.

Comment: I'm too having the same issue with a Google Slides file that is returning HTTP 413 error code when trying to download the file by its 'export_links' url. This worked for all of the tested large Google File scenarios, but there is one Google Slide file that returns an "HTTP/2 413". For the call of 'export_links' we get a redirection response and we follow up with that URL and we get the 413 error. Comparing request sent on this redirection(curl verbose) with successfully downloading large Google Slide doesn't see any noticeable difference even the redirection URL length is equal.

Comment: Sorry, I cant share this sample file, but is it possible to check whats the issue here.

Comment: Same here. I'm not able to share the file, but it looks like it has a lot of potentially large images. And it looks like not even downloading it in PPTX format (through the browser) works either. PDF does work.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this one?  We are seeing similar behaviour

Comment: @Matt I don't remember to be honest. It was some time ago and I'm longer working on that project. I don't *think* we managed to solve the issue.